# Compare items separated by comma in two column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with two columns, columns A and column B. Each column have items separated by a comma as shown below.

[image]

I would like to create a third column (column C) which returns the items that exists in column A but does not exist in column B

[image]

I'll appreciate any help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post images of data. Where do you hold the data, is it already a pandas dataframe or are we looking at an Excel screenshot, is it a text file representation..... Please clarify. If dataframe, post result of `df.head()` (as text, formatted as code,  i.e. indented) if textfile, post the first few lines, in the same way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set intersection. Notice that the performance will not be good if you use `pandas`, but it is possible

```
inter = ds.A.str.split(',').apply(set) - ds.B.str.split(',').apply(set).values
df['C'] = inter.str.join(',')
```

I'd suggest a pure Python approach, though.

```
df['C'] = [','.join(set(a.split(',')) - set(b.split(','))) for a,b in zip(ds.A, ds.B)]
```

Timings are clear

```
%timeit [','.join(set(a.split(',')) - set(b.split(','))) for a,b in zip(ds.A, ds.B)]
40.4 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit ds.A.str.split(',').apply(set) - ds.B.str.split(',').apply(set).values
730 µs ± 27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code (application of a function along *column* axis (1):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# Source data
df = pd.DataFrame( data={'A': [ 'Lisa, John, Sam', 'Lisa, John, Sam' ],
    'B': [ 'Lisa, Peter, Sam', 'Lisa, Peter' ] })
pat = re.compile(r',\s*')
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(\
    set(re.split(pat, x.A)) - set(re.split(pat, x.B))), axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
                 A                 B          C
0  Lisa, John, Sam  Lisa, Peter, Sam       John
1  Lisa, John, Sam       Lisa, Peter  John, Sam
```